# how to display a state which is passed as an object to another screen in react native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-native-ios

So I have created a state like :

```
const [inState, setInState] = useState([<View />]);
```

Then on click of some buttons, I am updating inState

```
const breakOutClick = () => {
    setInState([
        ...inState,
        <>
            <StatusBoxComponent
                ImageConfigIconCheckOut={true}
                status={'Break-Out'}
                time={time}
            />
        </>,
    ]);
};

const breakInClick = () => {
    setInState([
        ...inState,
        <>
            <StatusBoxComponent
                ImageConfigIconCheckOut={true}
                status={'Break-In'}
                time={time}
            />
        </>,
    ]);
};
```

I am able to display everything stored in inState, on this same screen in this manner:

```
<View>
    {inState}
</View>
```

I am passing this `inState` to another screen in the following manner:

```
props.navigation.navigate(ChartScreen, {
            inState: Object.assign({}, inState),
        });
```

Then on this second screen, i.e, ChartSCreen, I did the following:

```
const ChartScreen = (props: any) => {
    const {inState} = props.route.params;
    useEffect(() => {
    console.log('>>>>>>>>>', inState);
}, []);
    return (
        <View>
            {inState}    // getting error here
        </View>
    );
};
```

I have console the `inState`, which looks like this:

```
{
    "0": <ForwardRef />, 

    "1": <React.Fragment>
            <StatusBoxComponent 
                ImageConfigIconCheckOut={true} 
                status="Break-In" 
                time="17:51:40" 
            />
        </React.Fragment>, 
        
    "2": <React.Fragment>
            <StatusBoxComponent 
                ImageConfigIconCheckOut={true} 
                status="Break-Out" 
                time="17:51:42" 
            />
        </React.Fragment>
}
```

How can I display the multiple `StatusBoxComponent` on my second screen?

Answer (score 0):

You are displaying initially an array, but by calling `Object.assign({}, inState)` you're creating an object. Where you're getting the error, you're attempting to render that object, not an array of components. Try using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get only the values and virtually "restore" your initial array.

```
const ChartScreen = (props: any) => {
    const {inState} = props.route.params;
    useEffect(() => {
    console.log('>>>>>>>>>', inState);
}, []);
    return (
        <View>
            {Object.values(inState)}    // getting error here
        </View>
    );
};
```